# How do you properly have a .NET windows program resume from sleep?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-5

I have a simple .NET 5.0 executable written which is executing in a loop. Everything works fine but whenever Windows goes to sleep and resumes, the program's loop execution has stopped. Does anyone know how to properly handle cases like this? This is the simple

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

And then in Worker.cs I have this as the ExecuteAsync method.

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            CheckChangedClipboard();
            await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably it stops on Exception crashing the worker Thread. Use try-catch, also log if Token was canceled.

Comment: You could look at handling the Sleep/Resume events https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onpowerevent